# Work with two asynchronous calls in angualrjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I am currently new with promise concept of angularjs and finding my self stuck in asynchronus pyramid.

The situation is an asynchronus function which is calling another asynchronus function 2 on its success. The desired output is to perform some operations once both the functions are completly executed.

```
// Inside Controller    
         ServiceName.AsyncFunc1().then(function(){
               alert("Complete");     
         })


// Inside Service    
            app.service('ServiceName', function ($http) {
            return {
                AsyncFunc1 : function()
                {
                       var self = this;
                       return $http.post(url).
                       success(data)
                       {
                            self.AsyncFunc2();
                       }
                },
                AsyncFunc2 : function()
                {
                       return $http.post(url2).
                       success(data)
                       {
                            alert("AsyncFunc2 Complete");
                       }
                },
          }
    });
```

Now, I want alert("Complete") should be called when both the sequential asynchronous calls are completed.
But currently I am having alert("Complete") before alert("AsyncFunc2 Complete");

Comment: `return self.AsyncFunc2();`, also change `success` to `then`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your alert messages when both of the functions return a promise, then you can use `$q.all`

`$q.all` requires an array of promises.

Example

```
 $q.all([function1(), function2()])
```

**EDIT**
Ok! It that is the case, then you can just use then after the second sequential function is resolved. From your explanation this is what I understand.

```
(function(){
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);


  function MyController(myService) {

    function secondASyncSuccess() {
      alert("second function is done");
    }

    function firstFuncSuccess() {
     alert("First func is done");
      myService.secondASyncFunction()
        .then(secondASyncSuccess, secondASyncFailure);
    }

    myService.firstASyncFunction()
      .then(firstFuncSuccess, firstFuncFailure);
  }

})();
```

Comment: $q.all() works parallely but I want it to be sequential.

Comment: Try this. I hope this is what you mean by sequential $http calls execution through promises.